# Does the nw:eigenvector-centrality measure use the left (out-links) or right (in-links) eigenvectors in a directed network?

Tags: network-programming, netlogo

Does the calculation for eigenvector-centrality in the Netlogo network extension use in-links or out-links in a directed network to calculate the metric?